# Open custom URL from spotlight

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, spotlight

I'm trying to build an automation where I could type in Spotlight something like "open 234" and it will open a web browser to "https://myweb.com/234".

Is this possible in to do maybe using an Automator workflow or AppleScript?

Comment: Generally speaking I have the say the answer is no, unless you have an _application_ named **open 234**  that when opened from **Spotlight** opens a _browser_ to the target **URL**. In other words, in that example everything is _hard coded_.  What's the real use case for this? What are you really trying to accomplish here and why the need to use **Spotlight**?

Comment: Sure.  Create an applescript that takes its command line argument,  suffixes it to the URL, then uses open to cause the browser to load it.  The question is... why?

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up switching from Spotlight to Alfred. This task is easily attainable even without Powerpack, just go to `Features` -> `Web search` and add a custom provider.

Now I could view Jira ticket in Safari as simple as `cmd + space` -> `j 1111` -> `enter`.

Comment: Is Alfred free to use ?

Comment: As I understand the Alfred itself is free, but the Powerpack isn’t.